# Evento para actualizar un grid conforme las letras que vayan ingresando!

Tags: c#, asp.net

Resulta que quiero ir filtrando un GridView, conforme vayan ingresando letras en un TextBox.

Alguna recomendación a utilizar, algún evento en el TextBox que pueda utilizar ?

Gracias, Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es filtrar del lado del servidor puedes usar el evento `TextChanged` del `TextBox`, pero solo realizara el postback si asignas la propiedad `AutopostBack` en `true`

[Search and Filter GridView on TextBox OnTextChanged event in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-and-Filter-GridView-on-TextBox-OnTextChanged-event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

en el articulo define

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Search" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

para luego en el `Search()` aplicar el filtro, aunque cambiari un poco como lo aplica en el parametro

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{

    string sql = @"SELECT CustomerId, ContactName, City, Country FROM Customers
                    WHERE ((@ContactName IS NULL) || ContactName LIKE @ContactName + '%')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
    }

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    gvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

en lugar de condicionar armando el string se puede apliar filtros opcionales segun se asigne valor al parametro o no